# WPF: Change background color of a template

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I have defined a menu template which, in theory, should use the backgroundcolor of the "AppBackground" SoliColorBrush, defined in a separate file.

When in "debug mode", I use the following code to change that variable:
this.Resources["AppBackground"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);

This has the intended effect on the application background, however, it doesn't seem to have an effect on the custom menu design I have.  I have tried to use both StaticResource and DynamicResource, without any luck.  Is this a known issue, and is there a trick here?

Defined in ResourceDirectory:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBackground" Color="#003466"/>
```

Defined in a file:

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
              <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1">
                 <Grid Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppBackground}}">
```

Comment: How you are referring the Resouce Dictionary to your page is it through Application resources or local file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Havent seen that you marked that it works also not with DynamicBinding. I only looked at the code. Thats why I wrote my first answer:*

Use DynamicBinding, that should work.

The real problem **you wrapp the resource through a Binding. Remove this**, as I wrote in my other post. Sorry the chaos with the multiple answers.

**`<Grid Background="{DynamicResource AppBackground}">`**

Comment: " I have tried to use both StaticResource and DynamicResource"

Comment: Exactly, Dynamic doesn't cut it!  I belive it has to do something with the "templates" property.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a typing error: Remove the `{Binding...` and it works:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource AppBackground}">
```

The binding acts as a wrapper between the ressource and the destination and prevents the tracking of the changes.

Comment: Returns runtime error: "Cannot set propert on object '#FF003466' because it is in a read-only state.  Code is run in "OnStartup" function, under 'public partial class App : Application'